# Is it possible in es6 to instantiate a class and define prototype properties similar to a classical constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 when you create a class with prototype properties how can I set those props `baz` and `biz` on instantiation (`new`) of class?

```
class Foo {}

Foo.prototype.baz = 1;
Foo.prototype.biz = 'wow';

var thing = new Foo() // How to also set prototype values of .baz & .biz on creation?



class Baz {

  constructor(biz) {
   this.biz = biz
  }
}

var baz = new Baz(); // will not put properties on the prototype.
```

Comment: Make a constructor?

Comment: @Ultimater sorry slip

Comment: @SLaks a constructor will not put properties on the prototype.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood That's the whole point of doing it for every instance. If you don't want to do it for every instance, you wouldn't do it on creation.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @bergi I'm using jsDocs + closure compiler. I have a modal class let's call it  'Foo'. Foo defines the type (jsDoc) of an object.  Foo has all of it's properties on the prototype.  I need to call `new Foo()` and also set the value of a few of the properties e.g. biz and baz.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Those properties that you want/need to set for every instance, with possibly different values, are not properties you'd put on the prototype. "*Foo has all of it's properties on the prototype*" doesn't make much sense, if no instance had own properties they'd be indistinguishable and you wouldn't even need multiple instances, let alone that class. So why do you want to put everything on the prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is

```
class Baz {
  constructor(biz) {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).biz = biz
    // or
    // this.constructor.prototype.biz = biz
  }
}

const baz1 = new Baz(1); // baz1.biz === 1
const baz2 = new Baz(2); // baz2.biz === 2
baz1.biz === baz2.biz; // === 2
```

And it is not something the one would want to do in any reasonable scenario.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to simplify a bit of a more complicated scenario.  The blowback of this conversation is really educating me!  thanks for your help.

Comment: If you suppose that this is necessary for some real-world case, feel free to create a question that reflects your case, because it is most certainly should be solved in a different way. The code in the answer is not the worst class I've ever met, but it is in top 5.

Comment: I got clarity on my problem from a co-worker: exbit a: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Structural-Interfaces-in-Closure-Compiler

The problem is that my example of Foo is just a structural type not a model.  It's totally virtual and is used for nothing else than to set a type of an object.  I was trying to use is as a type and a model.  Thats just not its intention.

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor)` is `Function`. If you wanted to refer to `Baz.prototype`, it would need to be `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)`, but really you should statically refer directly to the object to avoid problems when inheritance is involved.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Ok then. I don't do Closure, but I guess there may be more idiomatic ways to handle this, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set prototype properties just like that, just like we did without using `class` syntax.

> How to also set prototype value on creation?

You cannot. Prototypes have nothing to do with instantiation. If you want instance properties, put them in the constructor, but they won't be prototype properties any more. If you want inherited properties, put them on the prototype, but they're shared between all instances and not created with every object.

Comment: Whats your feelings about: var foo = Object.create({baz: 'wow'}, {}) I'm just trying to do as much research as possible before i get negatived pointed to hell

Comment: My feeling is bad. There doesn't seem to be any reason to use that code over a simple `var foo = {baz: 'wow'};`. Or maybe it just lacks context.